# How to set locale to show time with my language?

Tags: vega-lite

I have standard timestamps in a time series, so I need X-axis showing time in my language (suppose `pt` not `en`) and standards of my country (suppose European or Brazilian but not US)... [There are no example](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/locale/) showing how to use it? Suppose the example bellow, how to add correct locale in it?

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "1995-10-11 09:00:00", "b": 28},
      {"a": "1995-10-12 09:00:00", "b": 30},
      {"a": "1995-10-13 15:00:00", "b": 34}
      {"a": "1995-12-17 03:00:00", "b": 29},
      {"a": "1995-12-17 09:00:00", "b": 31},
      {"a": "1995-12-17 15:00:00", "b": 30}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": { field": "a", "type": "temporal" },
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `timeFormatLocale` embed option to one of the locale JSON objects from [d3-format-locale](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/tree/master/locale).

Here is an example using the pt-BR locale setting:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    var spec = {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"a": "1995-10-11 09:00:00", "b": 28},
          {"a": "1995-10-12 09:00:00", "b": 30},
          {"a": "1995-10-13 15:00:00", "b": 34},
          {"a": "1995-12-17 03:00:00", "b": 29},
          {"a": "1995-12-17 09:00:00", "b": 31},
          {"a": "1995-12-17 15:00:00", "b": 30}
        ]
      },
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    };
    var embedOpt = {
      "mode": "vega-lite",
      "timeFormatLocale": {
        "dateTime": "%A, %e de %B de %Y. %X",
        "date": "%d/%m/%Y",
        "time": "%H:%M:%S",
        "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
        "days": ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
        "shortDays": ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"],
        "months": ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
        "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"]
      }
    };
    vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, embedOpt);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The rendered chart looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Near perfect!  How to change the period from AM/PM to 24 hours?  ... Or maybe it is a problem with `H` in the time format... My chart is only using `"type": "temporal"` but time series with days and hours (shows correct days),  when zoom-in shows incorrect hours.

Comment: Label formatting can be adjusted using the mechanisms documented in [Format](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/format.html).

Comment: Seems a VEGA *bug* because `"time": "%H:%M:%S"` say [`H`, not `p`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format),  and `H` is 24hs.  Anyway,  24 hs (**not** AM/PM) is part of the National Standard of a nation, so it is part of the Locale system.

Comment: If it is a **bug**, it  is interesting to check if it is a VEGA or a D3js bug...  A workaround is to use `"periods": []` to show only 12 hours, that is less polluted for Brazilian eyes than AM/PM in the temporal axes.

Comment: You should not modify the timeFormatLocale; you should modify the axis formats to specify 24 hour display. I'm not certain that 24hr display can be specified within the timeFormatLocale.

Comment: Ok,  it is a D3js bug: please check if it make sense, https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/issues/82

Comment: Hi, [Mike Bostock is suggesting there](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/issues/82#issuecomment-625535573) that it is a VEGA bug, maybe VEGA *"are using some other non-localized code that specifies `%I`, and you want to change that to use `%H`"*.  PS: I try to do the suggeste workaround but D3 for `d3.timeFormat(".%L")`, etc is not defined in VEGA-lite (how to call the D3 attached to VEGA?)